# Encoding problems in my servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I've been looking all the internet to find how i could fix my encoding problem...
I don't know why but when i post data with a  the data that a receive with my servlet have a encoding problem with characters like "é" or "è".

But when i put them in my database en get them from them in my servlet there is no problem.

In all my jsp files i have got this line to specify that i use UTF-8 :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

And to get my data from my form i use this line :

```
String justificatif = request.getParameter("justificatif");
System.out.println(justificatif);
```

I've tried to modify my tomcat server files (conf/server) transforming this

```
<Connector port="8080" ...
```

to this

```
<Connector port="8080" ... URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

but i doesn't affect anything

I don't know what to do, can someone help me ?

Comment: You can try using the Request.setEncoding("UTF-8") method, though  you've already tried changing your server.xml. Do you run Tomcat behind a web server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx man for the answer !

In my servlet before getting my data i've just call this method :

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String justificatif = request.getParameter("justificatif");
System.out.println(justificatif);
```